# Click delay in nextjs and the delay will disappear with scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, delay

When the site is loaded, all the clicks on every page are delayed, even after changing the route, but when I do a small scroll, the click delay disappears and the site can be used easily.This problem has a bad effect on the site's INP(seo). How can I solve this problem in nextjs 13?

Comment: I am using Next.js 13 and not experiencing any delay. Please share more details to reproduce the issue. You can also share codesandbox or similar